# How to derive the graph of any n-step transitions through a Markov chain

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Context: The code below produces the graph of a Markov chain with the transition probabilities shown on each edge. If I chose any vertex to start from, say vertex 1, I would then like the graph of all 2 steps through the Markov chain to be drawn along with the vertex labels shown. The graph would look like a tree diagram, with the root node (top node) being labeled 1, for instance.

```
g = DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 0, 0, 0}, {{0, 1/2, 0, 1/2}, {1/3, 0, 1/3, 1/3}, {0, 1/2, 0, 1/2}, {1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 0}}];
Graph[g, VertexStyle -> {1 -> Yellow, 2 -> Yellow, 3 -> Yellow, 4 -> Yellow}, EdgeLabels -> {DirectedEdge[i_, j_] :> MarkovProcessProperties[g, "TransitionMatrix"][[i, j]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Frankly, I still don't get what you want. Very likely that's why you got no answer. I withdrew my close vote and deleted my comment after your initial edit, but it's still not a well-phrased question. What you need is not a bounty but a clear explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an update after the OP clarified what they meant (old answer below):

```
step[_, _, 0] := {}
step[T_, p : (_ -> i_), n_] := Flatten@Table[
   If[T[[i, j]] > 0,
    {
     Property[p -> (p -> j), EdgeLabels -> T[[i, j]]],
     step[T, p -> j, n - 1]
     },
    Nothing
    ],
   {j, Length@T}
   ]

Graph[
 step[MarkovProcessProperties[g, "TransitionMatrix"], Begin -> 1, 2],
 VertexStyle -> Yellow,
 VertexSize -> 0.3,
 VertexLabels -> {(_ -> j_) :> Placed[j, {1/2, 1/2}]}
 ]
```

[image]

#### How this works

The `step` function recursively builds a list of edges. It gets 3 arguments:

- The transition matrix $T$
- The path to the current vertex (we pass along the full path to ensure that e.g. `1->3->1` and `1` are distinct vertices)
- The number of remaining steps

At each step, we create new edges corresponding to all non-zero entries of $T$, and call `step` again with the new vertex and `n-1`. At the end, we simply create a graph from the list of edges, where we use only the last part of the path as vertex label. The initial vertex is specified as `Begin->1` to ensure that it matches the pattern `_->i_`.

### Old answer

You can easily compute the transition probabilities for an $n$-step process using $T^n$, where $T$ is the transition matrix and $\square^\square$ denotes `MatrixPower`:

```
g2 = DiscreteMarkovProcess[
   {1, 0, 0, 0},
   MatrixPower[MarkovProcessProperties[g, "TransitionMatrix"], 2]
   ];
Graph[
 g2,
 VertexStyle -> {1 -> Yellow, 2 -> Yellow, 3 -> Yellow, 4 -> Yellow},
 EdgeLabels -> {
   DirectedEdge[i_, j_] :> MarkovProcessProperties[g2, "TransitionMatrix"][[i, j]]
   }
 ]
```

[image]

In this new Markov process represented by the graph above, a single step corresponds to exactly two steps in the original process.
From here, it is straightforward to get the representation you want:

```
g3 = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[
   MarkovProcessProperties[g2, "InitialProbabilities"]*MarkovProcessProperties[g2, "TransitionMatrix"] /. (0 -> Infinity)
   ];
Graph[
 g3,
 VertexStyle -> {1 -> Yellow, 2 -> Yellow, 3 -> Yellow, 4 -> Yellow},
 EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight",
 VertexSize -> 0.3,
 VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, {1/2, 1/2}]
 ]
```

This creates the graph from the given transition probabilities, which we get by multiplying the initial state with $T^n$ (1 element per row)

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for the tree diagram that forms from a 2-step transition, say startiing at Vertex 1

Comment: Can't you just build a tree graph using the first row of the transition matrix of `g2` to achieve that? Or am I misunderstanding what you're after?

Comment: It would be nice to have the tree graph generated automatically by choosing the starting vertex, say vertex 1 which would be row 1 of the T^2 matrix

Comment: @PRG I've updated the answer - is this what you meant?

Comment: Very close and many thanks! ... I was looking for a graph that generates ALL the intermediate transitions (from a starting vertex you choose) on the way to the transition state you want at the end (say 2nd transition). It would look like a classic "probability tree diagram"

Comment: At the top of the question, I added a picture of the graph I'd like to have automatically generated from any user selected starting vector as appropriate per the transition matrix. For example, row 1 in the T matrix is Vertex 1, shown as Cone 1. From there, the "tree diagram" of the intermediate transitions to the final desired transition (e.g., transition 2) is generated.

Comment: @PRG Like this?

Comment: @ Lukas Lang perfect!! Thank you for the creative coding ... prg